# Invalid character " ' " (Apostrophe) in html file generated by loading views in Codeigniter, causing a white overlay at the top of the page

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

please help me out, I've been stuck on this snag for a WHILE now. Basically I am loading views in codeigniter and for some odd reason, I get some white-space and an apostrophe. It makes the whole page look weird.

This is what I get when I view source in the browser

```
'

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Propercade Property</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="WEBLINERZ Landing Page Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="WEBLINERZ, unique, creative, html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Favicon -->   
    <link href="application/views/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
```

This is the header file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Propercade Property</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="WEBLINERZ Landing Page Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="WEBLINERZ, unique, creative, html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Favicon -->   
    <link href="application/views/img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon"/>
```

I am seriously stumped. This is how I load the page:

```
$this->load->view('header-index');
$this->load->view('index',$send);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Visually, this is what I see:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqJs4.png)

Please let me know if you have encountered a similar issue and how might I resolve this

*edit*

controller function:

```
public function index(){
        $this->load->model('Listing_model'); 
        $data1 = $this->Listing_model->get_recent_listing();
        $data2 = $this->Listing_model->get_featured_listing(6);//number of listings to get ~in case there are too many featured listings
        $send = array(
            "recents" => $data1,
            "listings" => $data2
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata("page_name", "Index");
        $this->load->view('header-index');
        $this->load->view('index',$send);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Turns out my output buffer was causing problems. Just needed to clean it.

```
ob_clean();
```

Funny how little things like this can cause so much issues

Comment: Have you tried to load the header alone and see if it is still there?

Comment: Yes I have tried, the apostrophe is still there if I only load the header

Comment: Ok good lemme see the code before that in your controller's method.

Comment: this is the whole controller function:

Comment: 'code'
public function index(){
     $this->load->model('Listing_model'); 
     $data1 = $this->Listing_model->get_recent_listing();
     $data2 = $this->Listing_model->get_featured_listing(6);//number of listings to get ~in case there are too many featured listings
     $send = array(
         "recents" => $data1,
         "listings" => $data2
     );
     $this->session->set_userdata("page_name", "Index");
     $this->load->view('header-index');
     $this->load->view('index',$send);
     $this->load->view('footer');
 }
'code'

Comment: Have you tried to load the view without any logic before it, just keep `$this->load->view('header-index');` in your `index()`

Comment: Yes, tried just now. Now I only get some white-space but no apostrophe

Comment: Turns out, if I don't have any logic before loading the page, it works fine. So, should I find another way load the data for the view?

Comment: You should make a template, you don't need to create so many header/footers and of course you don't need to load them in every single method which violates the DRY rule.

Comment: Righto, thanks for bearing with me. Could you point me to a tutorial for codeigniter templates? I am not aware of them

Comment: See my answer, its pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

How to keep it **DRY** and make it much easier to debug, first of all you need to create a `BASE_Controller` which in CodeIgniter prefixed by default with `MY_`, anyways, in your `application/core` create a new file called `MY_Controller` and create a class in it an let it extend `CI_Controller` and here is the basic code you need to add to it:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller 
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
            // Your own constructor code
    }

    // now lets create our own render view
    public function render_view($view)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $this->data);
        $this->load->view($view, $this->data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $this->data);
    }
}
```

Now in every other `controller` let it extend `MY_Controller` and use `render_view()` to load the view and you got your `header` and `footer` loaded for you and you don't need to repeat yourelf.

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        // note that you already have global data array from my_controller, now you don't need to pass it here to the view, its already passed in render_view
        $this->data['title'] = 'Hello World';

        $this->render_view('your_view');
    }
}
```

Of course there are way better approaches than this, you can create templates and use different layouts etc, but lets keep it simple for now, that's all you need.

Now in you view you can use `$title` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
    ...
```

Comment: @MoazzamAli follow this design.

Comment: Thanks, this does help. Good programming practice and a better way to do stuff. However, I found the issue. Needed to use ob_clean(); to flush the output buffer.

Comment: No it doesn't need any manual cleaning, you may have done something wrong.